# How to iterparse a zipfile object

Tags: python, xml, parsing, zip, elementtree

How can I convert a zipfile object to something useable for a iterparse function?

```
for name in zipfile.namelist():
xml_zip = zipfile.open(name, 'r')

for bla, elem in etree.iterparse(xml_zip):
    print bla
```

I've tried converting the zipfile object with .read() to a string. But that gives problems because it isn't in Unicode. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you should post a complete example, the code snippet you posted doesn't work, iterparse is not an attribute of etree module. this works:

```
import zipfile
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with zipfile.ZipFile('zipfile.zip') as z:
    for fname in z.namelist():
        with z.open(fname) as f:
            for event, elem in ElementTree.iterparse(f):
                print elem
```